# Vue.js & Java-Spring/Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, vue.js

I am currently working on some project where we added an API (it's java/spring project built by maven, running on tomcat, frontend are .jsp pages) so we have this dir structure:

`parent
   ├── core
   ├── webap (jsp pages)
   ├── api
   └── vue`

I am using vue cli 3 with vue ui and yarn. So there is some dist folder which needs to be served by a server but for some reason it doesn't work in tomcat the way my colleague set it. Does anyone please have experience with these kinds of projects? I need a hint. What is a good way to configure such a project. Or is it better to keep it as two separate projects?